# flutter : Text floating on the container margin or padding

Tags: flutter

iam trying to make a listview the item of it consist of

a row inside it 4 expanded containers

each container have a center widget inside it a text

the point is that i want to make a bottom margin for every item

but the text float on it when its needing a more space

and this is my code

first the listview

```
  Widget _buildList(List list , BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          String id = list[index]["default_code"].toString();
          String name = list[index]["name"].toString();
          String cate = list[index]["categ_id"][1].toString();
          String measure = list[index]["uom_id"][1].toString();
          return _buildTableRow(
              number: id,
              name: name,
              collection: cate,
              measure: measure,
              context: context);
        },
        itemCount: list == null ? 0:list.length,
        shrinkWrap: true,
      ),
    );
  }
```

and the TableRow

```
  Widget _buildTableRow(
      {@required String number,
      @required String name,
      @required String collection,
      @required String measure,
      @required BuildContext context}) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            bottom: BorderSide(
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            buildValueItem(number, context),
            buildValueItem(name, context),
            buildValueItem(collection, context),
            buildValueItem(measure, context)
          ],
        ));
  }
```

and the buildValueItem

```
Widget buildValueItem(String title, BuildContext context) {
  return Expanded(
    child: Container(
      height: 70,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0xFFCCCCCC),
        border: Border(
          left: BorderSide(
            color: Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            width: 1,
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
            fontFamily: 'main',
            color: Colors.black,
          ),
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

like this..

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1N2o.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make some changes:

- Remove the fixed height of your `Container` (70)
- Wrap your _buildTableRow inside `IntrinsicHeight`

Like this:

```
         return IntrinsicHeight(
                      child: _buildTableRow(
                      number: id,
                      name: name,
                      collection: cate,
                      measure: measure,
                      context: context),
                    );
```

...

```
Widget buildValueItem(String title, BuildContext context) {
            return Expanded(
              child: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
....
```

Comment: the same problem when iam adding a margin for the container its float on it also i want to make a margin that have another color or a border for the parent container like in the picture that i updated the post with it

Comment: what picture? I don't see any picture

Comment: the same problem

Comment: Could you upload an image about what you need?

Comment: i want the text not come on the white border .. like in the image i uploaded you will find the text is come over the white border

Comment: did you try removing Expanded from your container??

Comment: i need it to take the same size of the table head